# Isomorphism of a group $G = \left\langle x , y \mid x^5 = y^2 = e , x^2y = yx \right\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group whose representation is $G = \left\langle x , y \mid x^5 = y^2 = e , x^2y = yx \right\rangle$ . Then $G$ is isomorphic to

a) $\mathbb Z_5$

b) $\mathbb Z_2$

c) $\mathbb Z_{10}$

d) $\mathbb Z_{30}$

I think order of $G$ is 10, but how to show that $G$ is cyclic.

any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your presentation - in both versions. Please check it. As it stands, none of the options is correct. The group is infinite cyclic and  generated by $y$.

Comment: $x=e$ is not a contradiction because $e^5=e$ is true!

Comment: $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$, unless you meant $x^5=y^2=e$ and $x^2y=yx$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I was confused with the minimality off relations, i.e., that $x^2=e$ is minimal, hence $x\neq e$. I believe the OP does mean the relation $y^2=e$ instead of $x^2=e$ in the presentation.

Comment: Why not $y^5=x^2=e$, making a) the correct answer? Or perhaps the third relation should by $xy=yx$ making c) correct? Making d) correct is more of a challenge :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working under the assumption that the OP meant $G=\left\langle x , y \mid x^5 = y^2 = e , x^2y = yx \right\rangle$.  (He wrote $G=\left\langle x , y \mid x^5 = x^2 = e , x^2y = yx \right\rangle$, which makes the problem very trivial as it means $G=\langle y\rangle$ without restriction on $y$, so $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$.)

The subgroup $N:=\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $G$ of order $1$ or $5$.  The factor group $G/N$ is generated by $yN$, whence its order is $1$ or $2$.  Consequently, we have $|G|= |G/N|\cdot |N|$ is a divisor of $2\cdot 5=10$.

Now, if $N$ is of order $5$, then it follows that $G/N$ must be of order $2$ (otherwise, the relation $x^2y=yx$ would imply that $x^2=x$, which is a contradiction).  Consider the element $yx$.  We have $(yx)^2=yxyx=x^2yyx=x^3$.  Therefore, $(yx)^{10}=x^{15}=e$.  Note that $yx\neq e$ (as $y\notin N$).  If $(yx)^5=e$, then $\langle yx\rangle\neq N$ is another subgroup of $G$ of order $5$, but this contradicts the Second Sylow Theorem (alternatively, you can see that $N\cap\langle yx\rangle$ contains $x^3\neq e$, but as $N\cong\mathbb{Z}_5$, we must have $\langle yx\rangle=N$, a contradiction).  If $(yx)^2=e$, then $x^3=e$, which contradicts the assumption that $N$ is of order $5$.  Therefore, the order of $yx$ is exactly $10$.  This means $G=\langle yx\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, so $G$ is abelian.  Ergo, we have $xy=yx=x^2y$, leading to $x=e$, which is absurd.  Hence, $N$ is the trivial subgroup.

We have established that $x=e$.  That is, $G=\left\langle y\,|\,y^2=e\right\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is  $\{x,y:x^5=y^2=e, x^2 y=yx\}$ then answer is (b) i.e $z_2$ as $(x^2y)^2$ will give $x=e$ (use $x^2 y=yx$) so only y will remain and thus order of group is two.

Comment: @DietrichBurdeThat is simply not true!

Comment: $y^2=e$ is not one of the relations of the presentation!

Comment: if the relations are minimal then its o.k,

Comment: @DerekHolt "y2=e is not one of the relations of the presentation!" Yeah, and since x5=x2=e is absurd, and since the author of the question does not even correct it, you might want to direct your anger at them, not at this answerer.

Comment: You could equally easily hypothesize that the first two relations should have been $x^5=y^2=e$, in which case a) would be the correct answer. I was also not completely certain that the third relation was as intended!

Comment: I have done typo mistake and extremly sorry for this , further i will take care .